# Tkinter canvas don't update on scrolling

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

The Canvas(blue area) din't get update on scrolling. It updates only if I resized the window.
So, where is the issue. I want to get the Canvas updated while scrolling.

```
class ScrollBar:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, bg='blue')
        self.scroll_y = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, bg='pink')

        #insert Widgets
        self.create_widgets()

        #Configure frame in canvas
        self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame, anchor='nw')

        #Update scrollregion
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'),yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y.set)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
        self.scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right')

        #Configure resized window
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_frame)
        
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        for i in range(20):
            Button(self.frame, text=f'Button {i}').grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='nsew', pady=2)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))
        
    def resize_frame(self,event):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, height=event.height, width=event.width)


root = Tk()
ScrollBar(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAq0o.png)

Comment: remove `height=event.height` from `self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, height=event.height, width=event.width)` -> `self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width=event.width)` the height mostly will be out of the visible canvas but `event.width` returns the height of the visible canvas

Comment: You need to update the `scrollregion` of `self.canvas` whenever `self.frame` is resized by binding `<Configure>` on `self.frame`.